# Angular 6 Typescript function not updating global variables globally

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 6.0.3 and am trying to use a progress handler when uploading a file to an ipfs daemon. The file is being uploaded correctly, but the variables that I use in my handler are not updating outside of the handler() function. Both of these functions are contained within a single component.

I assume this is some tricky typescript/javascript scope problem, but I can't seem to figure it out. Anybody got any pointers?

```
//we have a global variable that we use to check if we have started uploaded
isUploading = false;
```

This is the uploadFile function

```
uploadFile() {

  //We load data into a buffer
  const buf = new Buffer("string");

  //Then we write the buffer to the ipfs daemon
  this.ipfs.files.add(buf, {progress:this.handler})
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("Result isUploading = " + this.isUploading);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
}
```

This is the handler function

```
handler (p) {
  this.isUploading = true;
  console.log("Handler isUploading = " this.isUploading);
}
```

Explicitly, the **isUploading** value will be true in the **handler()** function and false in the **uploadFile()** function!

Comment: `this.isUploading` is not the same as referencing a global `isUploading`. Maybe this causes the confusion?
Edit: Or is `isUploading` a field of your component? Then it is not a global variable. In this case it might be helpful to post your whole component.

Comment: Try defining `handler` as an arrow function: `handler = (p) => { ... }`.

Comment: Or using bind() `{progress:this.handler.bind(this)}`